# Swift If you specify a non-nil format dictionary in your settings, your delegate must respond to the selector captureOutput:didFinishProcessingPhoto

Tags: swift, xcode, avfoundation, avcapturesession, ibaction

The code I am using below is supposed to take a photo and then convert the image to base64 in order to send it to a server. The code worked taking the photo, converting it to base64, and uploading it to my server but has stopped working. I have tried using other stack overflow posts to solve this issue but it has not worked for me. Thanks for any responses in advance!

Error

> Thread 1: Exception: "*** `-[AVCapturePhotoOutput capturePhotoWithSettings:delegate:]` If you specify a non-`nil` format dictionary in your settings, your delegate must respond to the selector `captureOutput:didFinishProcessingPhoto:error:`, or the deprecated `captureOutput:didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer:previewPhotoSampleBuffer:resolvedSettings:bracketSettings:error:`"

Code:

```
@IBAction func takePhotoButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
      let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
      let previewPixelType = settings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!
      let previewFormat = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: previewPixelType,
                           kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: 160,
                           kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: 160]
      settings.previewPhotoFormat = previewFormat
      sessionOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
}
        

func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
    let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation()
    let base64String = imageData?.base64EncodedString()
    print(base64String!)
}
```

Comment: Do you understand the error message?

Comment: I do not understand it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break down the error message:

- > Thread 1: Exception:

  An Objective C exception was thrown from Thread 1 of your program (that's probably the main thread). Not particularly interesting/insightful.
- > `-[AVCapturePhotoOutput capturePhotoWithSettings:delegate:]`

  This syntax describes the Objective-C method that threw the exception. The method's selector is `capturePhotoWithSettings:delegate:`, and it belongs to the `AVCapturePhotoOutput` class. The `-` indicates that it's an instance method (where a `+` would have indicated it's a class method).
- > If you specify a non-nil format dictionary in your settings ...`

  This is the case, you called `capturePhoto(with: settings, ...` with settings that aren't `nil`.
- > your delegate must respond to the selector `captureOutput:didFinishProcessingPhoto:error:`

  The system is complaining that you passed a delegate that does not respond to the selector [`captureOutput:didFinishProcessingPhoto:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotocapturedelegate/2873949-captureoutput?language=objc) (In Swift, the method is imported as [`photoOutput(_:didFinishProcessingPhoto:error:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotocapturedelegate/2873949-photooutput)).

  That is, your delegate doesn't define any methods with that name. You decided to pass `self` (whatever that is, I don't know without context) as the delegate: `capturePhoto(..., delegate: self)`.

  Whatever the type of `self` is, it already conforms to the `AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate` protocol (or else this would never have compiled). But it does not implement this method, which is optional by the protocol, but mandatory in this context.
- > or the deprecated `captureOutput:didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer:previewPhotoSampleBuffer:resolvedSettings:bracketSettings:error:`

  This is just telling you that instead of `captureOutput:didFinishProcessingPhoto:error:`, you could instead fix this issue by implementing `captureOutput:didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer:previewPhotoSampleBuffer:resolvedSettings:bracketSettings:error:`, but since that's deprecated, you probably shouldn't use it.

So in all, whatever the type of `self` is, you need to make sure it implements the method `photoOutput(_:didFinishProcessingPhoto:error:)`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue on my colleague's project. The delegate method is present but the error persists. Upon investigation, I noticed that the class is declared `public`. The issue is finally fixed by declaring the delegate method `public` as well:

```swift
public class SomePublicClass {
    // Some code here
}

extension SomePublicClass: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
    public func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.